# Temperature change when volume halved

Tags: thermodynamics

For this multiple question:

> [image]

The correct answer is B. However, I don't understand.

You are halving the volume
so for the original solution
the number of moles of HCl is 0.1 moles
and in the new solution, the number of moles of HCl is 0.05 if we are using the same concentration.

Therefore as there are less number of moles, won't the temperature increase (ie. energy release) get halved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is B in both the case the final concentrations are not changing. Therefore same will be the heat of rise. But heat released will be less but volume of the final solution also got halved. So temp. raise will be same.